# System.IO.Directory in .NET for Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

Question is very simple:

I'd like to achieve similar functionality to `System.IO.Directory` class (especially methods related to getting directories) in Windows Store Apps.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150593.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [StorageFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227230) class and let me know if it does what you look for.